# C# add-in for application (via COM) freezes when a Control is added to the form?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, com

I am developing an extension for existing application via `COM.`

Current interface of the application to extend allows **to create custom property windows** and use them inside that application.

---

*Now, I am using `.NET` for that purpose and have strange problems:*

```
    extensionForm = new Form();
    extensionForm.SetBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
    extensionForm.Controls.Add(new Button());
       
    ExApplAPI.AddCustomPropertyWindow(extensionForm.Handle.ToInt32(), "Ololo");
```

As you can see below, the property sheets *actually get extended*, but after that something strange starts to happen.

[image]

Basically, if I switch to `Ololo` tab, then back to any of other 3 tabs (`Attributes`, `Drawing` or `Services`), **the application freezes.** I also know that the freeze happens inside of some unmanaged code block.

---

Another interesting fact here is that if I don't write the `extensionForm.Controls.Add(new Button())` *(with or without the Suspend / Resume Layout calls)*, **everything works fine.** So, if the recently constructed form has no controls (buttons or any other) on it, *it doesn't freeze.*

Here is a `Spy++` log on the `Ololo` window right before the freeze (last message is the `WM_CTLCOLORBTN`, right after that the application became frozen):

[image]

---

### Combining everything together:

- Freezing happens only if I switch from `Ololo` to some other tab and then switch to the `Ololo` tab again.
- Freezing only happens if the integrated form has at least **one control on it,** forms without controls don't freeze.
- Application is not running any managed code at the moment and is not spending any CPU time.

**So - any ideas / similiar problems solved / etc to help me in this case?**

Comment: It depends on what is done in AddCustomPropertyWindow. A WinForm is not supposed to be hosted/parented. You could try a Control/UserControl instead. Otherwise, is it possible for you to post some sample code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I think you should provide a bit more of code for us to identify the problem please, I am pretty sure, its not just the button control, if you will do anything to the tab "Ololo" it will freeze your application, + Did you tried to create another tab, i mean just play around with your application, + try to debug and find where it's stucks, sometimes you get exceptions in code but it doesn't shows them as errors.

Comment: I agree, you should use some control (maybe derived from Panel) instead of Form. If you need to display same thing in a window, just host it in a Form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Win32 `HWND` handles for the Forms in .NET are lazy initialized. 
And I think this may be a problem here.

You may argue that the handle is created in your line `ExApplAPI.AddCustomPropertyWindow(extensionForm.Handle.ToInt32(), "Ololo");` due to accessing `Handle` property.
It is true and what [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx) acknowledges.

However, it creates the handle for the `Form` itself, but handles for child controls (`Button` in this case) are not created. This can be forced by calling `CreateControl` method. See [more documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createcontrol.aspx).

I don't know if not having a handle for button may be a cause of your problem, but this is definitely something I would investigate.

To summarize, I suggest changing your code to:

```
extensionForm = new Form();
extensionForm.SetBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
extensionForm.Controls.Add(new Button());

extensionForm.CreateControl();
ExApplAPI.AddCustomPropertyWindow(extensionForm.Handle.ToInt32(), "Ololo");
```

Answer (score 1):

Are there any exception thrown?
We had an similar behavior when using WPF and COM, it solved by calling reset double calculation by using

[DllImport("msvcr70.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int _fpreset();

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the resource handle is not right. As you mentioned this happens only when the integrated form has atleast one control in it, Ololo tab is not able to find it's resources when active again. Please try storing resource handle the first time and then restoring it everytime the tab is active.

Answer (score 0):

To understand why the application hangs, there are 2 things that may help:

1. Can you post a stack trace of the UI thread while the application is hung?
2. Which thread calls your code and actually creates the windows?